# Is it possible to create interactive videos using Adobe Animate CC

Tags: flash, video, jquery-animate, adobe, interactive

I'd like to create interactive videos that work with an HTML 5 compatible browser. Essentially i'd like to have hotspots pop up at certain points of the video and clicking on them will jump to a certain part of the video. For now I am using Adobe Animate, but I am open to other suggestions.

Thanks in advance.